# Windows Runtime access file from JavaScript in WebView

Tags: c#, javascript, webview, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1

I am using Three.js to try and implement a cross platform 3D model viewer. At the moment I have got it working and embedded in my XAML and C# application for Win 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 with a WebView. At the moment I am using C# code to load models (triangle meshes) from files on the device as well as a bundled file. The problem is that this means that I have to invoke a JavaScript function from C# for every triangle that I want to add and this makes the UI unresponsive for a while. I have tried to run the script async and to run the loader async but it does not really help because the all the JS function calls need to be handled by the Core Dispatcher otherwise I get an invalid thread access exception. In the beginning I did not realize this and thought it would be simpler and of higher performance to do loading in C#. I will now probably have to redo the loader in JS...

What I need to ask now is for some information as of how I should access the files from of JavaScript. I know Windows RT supports its file access API from JS but I am guessing this is more for entire JS applications because it does not seem to work from inside the WebView*. I would also prefer something more cross platform though as this also needs to work for Windows Desktop, iOS, Android and probably Mac and Linux too, so what would be my best option for this?

*I have tried the JS at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker.aspx in my WP 8.1 application but no file selector appears. My the WebView does seem to freeze up though but I also don't get any exceptions or so popping up.

PS. I have a sort of feeling that it might come down to me having to copy files to a temp folder that JS can access. This would not be ideal as copying will waste time but if it's my only option then I will probably have to go for it. If this my only option I would appreciate some help with implementing it because JavaScript is really not my language and I'm only using it because of Three.JS...

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

As soon are you're using the WebView you end up in a situation where you need to post messages back and forward between your host app (the C# code, assuming you didn't rewrite it) and the website you're hosting in the WebView. The two basically function in isolation from each other.

Can you not load your geometry using the documentation of the Three.js format? It looks to be available here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/JSON-Geometry-format-4

That way you can proxy the entire geometry across vs. each individual triangle.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not studying that I want to do because the models might be quite large and I don't want to have to shift a string for the whole thing as memory will be constrained.